# Loopback 3 with loopback-component-storage hang on POST file

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I've a very simple server running under loopback 3 and seeing this issue again: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-storage/issues/9

As the gists and examples don't work any longer I would like to reopen that issue.
I've created a very simple API templated server and added the following code:

```
module.exports = function (File) {
    File.upload = function (ctx, options, cb) {
        if (!options) options = {};
        ctx.req.params.container = 'common';

        console.log("DO");
        File.app.models.Storage.upload(ctx.req, ctx.result, options, function (err, fileObj) {
            console.log("FILE");
            cb(fileObj);

        });
    };

    File.remoteMethod(
        'upload',
        {
            description: 'Uploads a file',
            accepts: [
                {arg: 'ctx', type: 'object', http: {source: 'context'}},
                {arg: 'options', type: 'object', http: {source: 'query'}}
            ],
            returns: {
                arg: 'fileObject', type: 'object', root: true
            },
            http: {verb: 'post'}
        }
    );

};
```

The problem is now, that while posting via POSTMAN to the upload function, I see the following behavior in the console:

```
DO
Error: Request aborted
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (...../server/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:120:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at abortIncoming (_http_server.js:383:9)
    at socketOnClose (_http_server.js:377:3)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:504:12)
FILE
```

And Postman returns an empty response...

I'm totally lost as a beginner here at this step!

What is my fault here?

Thx for any input

Answer (score 2):

OMG, it seems that I've found the answer:

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-storage/issues/86

Just use Header "Accept" with value "multipart/form-data", not setting "Content-type". That works for me from Postman

Comment: I've now also filed a bug ... Maybe someone at IBM will fix this: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-storage/issues/196

Comment: How did you submit the file input from postman? As binary or form-data? Can you show an example of the input.